# Loading Codable data from URL

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm building an app to fetch and display data from https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json.

I've created following structs:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [User]
}

struct User: Codable {
    struct Friend: Codable {
        var id: String
        var name: String
    }
    
    var id: String
    var isActive: Bool
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var company: String
    var email: String
    var address: String
    var about: String
    var regiestered: Date
    var tags: [String]
    var friends: [Friend]
}

let urlString = "https://www.hackingwithswift.com/samples/friendface.json"
```

Then I try loading data using function like this:

```
func loadData () {
        guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            if let data = data {
                if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.results = decodedResponse.results
                    }
                    return
                }
            }
            print("Fetch failed: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown error")")
        }.resume()
    }
```

But when running the app I get "Unknown error" output. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Print `error` instead of `error.localizedDescription`, but are you saying that `data` is nil then? Also, you are ignoring the decoding error (if there was one), with you `try?`? What's `reponse` when it fails?

Comment: as posted by Larme you should try/catch the son decoding . 'error' is only the url session error and in your case is not set because you retrieved the dara. May be a typo : you wrote "regiestered" instead of "registered". Did you check that all fields are always present in JSON ?

Comment: You can also check https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-use-iso-8601-dates-with-jsondecoder-and-codable for decoding JSON Date in swift

Comment: regiestered is a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code.
First there is a typo in your User property. It should be registered instead of regiestered.
Second you are trying to decode a Response instead of an array of users.
Third you are not setting the dateDecodingStrategy to iso8601.
Fourth you are ignoring the error. Don't use try? catch the error and check what your decoder is throwing.

---

```
struct User: Codable {
    let id: String
    let isActive: Bool
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let company: String
    let email: String
    let address: String
    let about: String
    let registered: Date
    let tags: [String]
    let friends: [Friend]
}
```

---

```
struct Friend: Codable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

---

```
do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
    let users = try decoder.decode([User].self, from: data)
    // your code
} catch {
    print("Decode error:", error)
    return
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much, you really gave me a hand!